# Coordinate-wise continuity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I'm a bit confused by cooridnate-wise continuity.
What would it mean for the function:

$f(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2} & (x,y)\neq (0,0) \\
0 & (x,y) = (0,0)
\end{cases}$

to be continuous coordinate-wise?

Comment: "Separately continuous" would mean: for each fixed $x$ it is a continuous function of $y$, and for each fixed $y$ it is a continuous function of $x$.  But I do not know the term "coordinate-wise continuous" for a function of two variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I  think they mean "continuous in each variable separately". This means that $\lim_{x \to c} f(x,y)=f(c,y)$ for each $c,y$, and similar with limits in $y$. In other words, the functions $f_y$ defined by $f_y(x)=f(x,y)$ are continuous for each $y$, and similar for $x$.

Your example is continuous in each variable separately. When neither $x$ nor $y$ is zero, it is jointly continuous (it is a product of continuous functions provided you avoid $(0,0)$). If we now fix $y=0$ and consider $x \to 0$, then $f(x,0)=0$ so $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x,0)=0=f(0,0)$. The situation is the same with limits in $y$.

It is not jointly continuous, because the limit at $(0,0)$ is dependent on path: along the path $(x(t),y(t))=(t,0)$ we get zero (by the above), but along the path $(x(t),y(t))=(t,t)$ we get $\frac{1}{2}$.