# Introductory Analysis

Tags: real-analysis

I am struggling with this idea:

Suppose for some closed interval $I=[c,d]$,

For any function $f(x,y)$ on $[c,d]^2$, the infinitely many functions $g_{x_0}(t)=f(x_0,t),h_{y_0}(t)=f(t,y_0)$ obtained by fixing any particular $x_0$ or $y_0$ are uniformly continuous on $[c,d]$. we have for any point $i\in I$ the function $f_i=g_i(t)=f(i,t)$. 
 Intuitively, I would think this is true:

For all $a\in I$,$\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|x-a|<\delta$ and $x\in I$ implies $|f_x(x)-f_x(a)|<\epsilon$.

However, when trying to prove this, I run into a circular problem with there being infinitely many functions. Since x could be any of the infinitely values in $(a-\delta, a+\delta)$. There are infinitely many functions $f_x(x)$, I know each of them is uniformly continuous, so there exists $\delta_1, \delta_2....$How would I deal with this case, I can't be possibly saying let $\delta = min\{\delta_1, \delta_2,\delta_3....\}$, because that would shorten the interval and decrease the number of uncountable deltas too. Please offer some insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick a countable family of dense subsets of the interval, $A_1, A_2,...$. For each point x, define $f_x(y) = y^n$, if x is in $A_n$. (Let's make the interval [2,3].)

I think this is a counter example.

Comment: What if I add the constraint: for any function $f(x,y)$ on $[c,d]^2$, the infinitely many functions $g(t)=f(x_0,t),h(t)=f(t,y_0)$ obtained by fixing any particular $x_0$ or $y_0$ are uniformly continuous on $[c,d]$. And now instead of a general function $f_i$, we define for any $i\in I$, the function $f_i=g(t)=f(i,t)$. Would my claim be true now?

Comment: @JesseMeng I think it may be true if you put some restrictions on f, such as that it is uniformly continuous as a function of two variables. (But why do you want something like this to be true?)

Comment: I am working on the problem: for a function f on $[c,d]^2$, suppose for every $x\in[c,d]$ , the vertical slice $f_x$ is continuous on [c,d], and for every $y\in[c,d]$, the horizontal slice $h_y$ is continuous on [c,d]. Then does it follow that the function $w(t)$ on $[c,d]=f(t,t)$ is continuous on $[c,d]$? and my question deals with an intermediate step in the process. I started off with epsilon delta definition of continuity and splitted $|f(x,x)-f(a,a)|$ into $|f(x,x)-f(x,a)|+|f(x,a)-f(a,a)|$, which are the slicings, but it seems like there are infinitely many values for x.

Comment: the right side is easy, because it deals with the horizontal slicing at a particular point, but the left side deals with the vertical slicings at some interval of points, we know each vertical slicing is continuous, but how do we find a delta such that all of the vertical slicings are continuous?

Comment: @JesseMeng https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1149333/54092

Comment: Thank you, this solves my problem perfectly.